# How to seperate even and odd numbers in the same array?

Tags: java, arrays

How would I separate even and odd integers in an array **with order preserved**?

Modifications must be in place and the return is a `void`, and can only use built in methods.

An example would be:

```
{4, 5, 8, 16, 45, 12, 67, 13} -> {4, 8, 16, 12, 5, 45, 67, 13}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Any idea? What exactly is unclear to you? Please see [ask]. Downvoted for unclear.

Comment: Just think about which condition allows you to swap to numbers. And how to check if the array is already in the correct required order.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

You can easily solve this with one iteration, remembering the index of the current *border* and swapping elements.

So for your example, the process will be:

```
{ 4, 5, 8, 16, 45, 12, 67, 13 } // swap 4 with 4
  ^

{ 4, 5, 8, 16, 45, 12, 67, 13 }
     ^

{ 4, 8, 5, 16, 45, 12, 67, 13 } // swap 5 with 8
        ^

{ 4, 8, 16, 5, 45, 12, 67, 13 } // swap 5 with 16
            ^

{ 4, 8, 16, 12, 45, 5, 67, 13 } // swap 5 with 12
                 ^
```

Where the `^` shows the current border index, which is always one ahead of the even values, pointing at the index where you want to swap the next even value to.

---

### First draft

Here is the code for that:

```
int borderIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    int value = values[i];
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
        // swap
        values[i] = values[borderIndex];
        values[borderIndex] = value;
        borderIndex++;
    }
}
```

---

### Preserving order

Now, this solution already preserves the order of the even numbers out of the box. But if you pay close attention you see that it does not preserve order of the odd values. It goes wrong as soon as you have multiple odd values after each other before an even value, like

```
..., 5, 45, 12, ...
```

because it will then swap `5` with `12` resulting in `12, 45, 5` instead of `12, 5, 45`.

Even worse when there are multiple odd values:

```
..., 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, ...
```

resulting in `12, 7, 9, 11, 5`.

In order to fix this, we have to not just swap `5` with the even value `12` but actually swap all the way back to `5`. So:

```
swap 12 with 11
swap 12 with 9
swap 12 with 7
swap 12 with 5
```

basically shifting down `12` from right to left, until it stands right in front of `5`.

We can do so easily with a simple loop that moves from `12` (at `i`) to `5` (at `borderIndex`):

```
int borderIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    int value = values[i];
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
        // swap from i to borderIndex
        for (int j = i; j > borderIndex; j--) {
            values[j] = values[j - 1];
            values[j - 1] = value;
        }
        borderIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. The code does not work for me. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @jvvgg It works for me, I have tested it. Make sure to use the last snippet in the code (very bottom). If that doesnt work for you, please show your full code. Here is an example of how it looks in my test https://i.imgur.com/3ujOvSt.png

Comment: There was a small typo which I did not have in the code I tested with, sorry for that. Try it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like this.  In this case your sorting them on their inherent nature as opposed to their relationship to each other.

```
Integer [] arr = {4, 5, 8, 16, 45, 12, 67, 13};
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(a->a % 2));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

prints

```
[4, 8, 16, 12, 5, 45, 67, 13]
```